# Bit coin as equity

Tags: mining-pool-shares

Can we use Bit coin as equity for company shares. How do we exchange the bit coin for real money the banks will accept?

Comment: You convert property to money by a process that is referred to as "selling". You sell bitcoins by going to a company that specializes in bringing buyers and sellers together such as coinbase, gemini, bitstamp, or kraken.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of using Bitcoin as equity shares would be? But you can convert Bitcoin to fiat easily:
https://gemini.com
https://coinbase.com
[https://xcoins.io](https://xcoins.io/?r=6377u7)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your intention, the answer is no. A Bitcoin represents a bitcoin, and not your company or a share thereof it.

What you CAN do is create either a crypto currency yourself and sell it as shares, or run a contract on the Ethereum network.

However, I cannot, in good faith, say this is a good idea. You would be better served with a proper crowd-funding campaign or similar, if being listed on an equity exchange is not an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use crypto coin as the shares of your company, you can use Ethereum core. It is opensource, you can always use it to create a new crypto with smart contracts. 
You can use ethereum as some community currency, some type of stock/share auction, online auction, even for selling BTC!!!